# mediaelement.js wave files do not play in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, mp3, html5-audio, mediaelement.js, wave

I've installed mediaelement.js and created a page to dynamically render players on a page for user selected audio files. Some are mp3's, but others are wave files. The mp3's work nicely in IE (version 9 is all I can test at the moment) but wave files render a player but do not load the file. Both wave and MP3 files load and play fine in Chrome and also on my Android phone.

Can anyone shed a little light on getting my wave files to play?

Thanks!

Geo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, IE doesn't support WAV.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#.3CAudio.3E_element_format_support

Comment: That's incredible - especially since MS invented the .wav format.